# Can I access variable X in function B, if it is located in function A, which call function B?

Tags: python

Sorry if it is confusing; making an example.

```
def functionA():
    x=10
    b()

def functionB():
    Y=22
    return Y
```

Is there a way to access x from B, without pass it as parameter when I call B?
I would like to avoid to have to do something like

```
def functionB(var):
```

From my understanding, I can't call super because B is not part of A, it is just called from it. I would like to call B from A, and access in B a variable in A (or more than one; I am exploring the concept); but without pass it as parameter to B.

Is this even possible in Python?

Comment: It is possible, but it is never sane.

Comment: I'm curious, how is it even possible? Also, `super` doesn't make sense in this context because you're not writing classes, just functions.

Comment: Yes, the super was out of question since B is not subclass of A, as I mentioned in the question. Since I am a beginner at Python, I didn't know if there was some workaround that is both safe and easy

Comment: This is basically a way of using class encapsulation as a way to define single responsibilities to private sections of a set of code. For example, if your code needs to validate data, then act on it, you could have a public method on the class called process, then process calls an internal method __validate, and another __do_stuff. Once you do this, its really easy to use MagicMock and unit testing to validate your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if both are just functions, no. but if you made both functions methods of a containing class, you could make a's variable accessible to fuction b's.

```
class Wrapper(object):
  def __init__():
    self.a_val = None

  def functionA(self):
    self.a_val = 123
    self.functionB()

  def functionB(self):
     # you can access self.a_val here fine.
```

once you have this, you would call functionA as

```
Wrapper().functionA()
```

Comment: This looks feasible; in this way it has the pros of a global, without the dangers. Thanks!

Comment: wow, yeah global specifier looks nifty, but it breaks scope concepts and in general is something I would avoid

Comment: Actually it *is* possible with regular functions.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you actually can:

```
import inspect

def A():
    X = 42
    B()

def B():
    print(inspect.stack()[1][0].f_locals['X'])

A()
```

**But you shouldn't.**

Comment: Interesting. And scary.

Answer (score 3):

Here come the downvotes. 
This is how you can make sure you only execute it when the caller is "functionA" and you retrieve it's last local value before the call.

This is very sketchy though. Don't do this.

```
import sys

def functionA():
    x=10
    x = 5
    functionB()
    x = 3

def functionB():
    frame = sys._getframe()
    outer = frame.f_back
    if outer.f_code.co_name == "functionA":
        print outer.f_locals["x"]
    Y=22
    return Y
```

Comment: Nice one! Well Ok, I know it's wrong, but OP already has a serious answer, so I guess we can troll a little bit, right? :)

Comment: @MartinE.Zulliger;  I already see that you gave the shorter version of this via dicts. I always love to pad on dangerous looking functions with `_` and `__` to make it more scary for OP. Hopefully a successful deterrent method. Python forward declaration is but a step away!

Comment: Dangerous is relative...if it is for work, the less risk the better it is, but mostly I am fascinated to see how many ways there are to accomplish a task; which may carry a high quantity of gunpowder, the more creative it gets

Answer (score 1):

Well yes, what you want is a global variable:

```
def functionA():
    global x
    x=10
    functionB()

def functionB():
    Y=22
    print 'X from B:', x
    return Y

functionA()
```

Of course as any responsible programmer would tell you, be careful with global variables as they can easily turn your code into spaghetti.

The standard way to do that is, naturally, to use a class...

However, for argument sake, there is another way to do it, that will make that variable shared between those two functions and still not be global, using a closure:

```
def defineFuns():
    global functionA, functionB

    x = 10
    def functionA():
        print 'X from A:', x
        functionB()

    def functionB():
        Y=22
        print 'X from B:', x
        return Y

defineFuns()
functionA()
```

Or playing with the function's dictionary...

```
def functionA():
    x = 10
    print 'X from A:', x
    functionB.func_globals['x'] = x
    functionB()

def functionB():
    Y=22
    print 'X from B:', x
    return Y

functionA()
```

Comment: Good point about making it global, but this is quite scary since it may be modified anywhere....I was trying to access it only from B, so nothing else can touch it. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Indeed, it is dangerous because it is visible everywhere. The other option you have, as suggested by Nathan, is to put it inside a class. That is usually the standard approach... Umm Im thinking another way, using a closure...

Comment: Last one doesn't really do it. If you change A's variable x after giving its value to function and before calling functionB, then functionB will still have the old value. It doesn't have access to A's variable.

Comment: I know, but if X was an object, it would be the same instance, and hence it would be shared. The trick is not so useful with immutable objects, as you said.

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect case for nested functions.

```
def a():
    x = 10
    def b():
        y = 22 + x
        return y
    b()
```

Function b returns 32 (22+10).  The `x` in function `b` is the same as the `x` in `a`.  You can't call `b` from outside of `a`, but that makes perfect sense because the value of x would be undefined in that case.

Comment: Agree; once the var goes out of scope is done; although I believe the class approach is more solid than the nested function. Thanks!